# How to plot to subplots during a loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, matplotlib, subplot

How can I create one plot for this loop?

I want to create some subplots according to `i` values taken from the loop. Do I need to create a new `For/Loop` which goes to each subplot? How can I do it?. This is my code:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=3)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
fig.suptitle('Main plots')
for i in range(1,13):
  month = [i]
  DF_sub = DF[DF['months'].isin(month)]
  out = pd.cut(DF_sub['new'], bins=[0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1], include_lowest=True)
  out_norm = out.value_counts(sort=False, normalize=True)
  ax = out_norm.plot.bar(rot=0, color="b", figsize=(6,4))
  plt.title('Subplot -' + str(i))
```

Up to now, I just get the last one, but I am missing the previos `i`-s values from the loop

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the [`ax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot) parameter to `plot.bar` to specify on which of your `axes`, returned from `plt.subplots`, the bar chart should be plotted, i.e.:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=3)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
fig.suptitle('Main plots')
for i in range(1,13):
    month = [i]
    ax = axes[i - 1]
    DF_sub = DF[DF['months'].isin(month)]
    out = pd.cut(DF_sub['new'], bins=[0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1], include_lowest=True)
    out_norm = out.value_counts(sort=False, normalize=True)
    out_norm.plot.bar(rot=0, color="b", figsize=(6,4), ax=ax)
    plt.title('Subplot -' + str(i))
```

If you don't pass the `ax` parameter, the bar chart will automatically be plotted on the currently active axis, which is the one most recently created unless set otherwise.

Comment: To complete the answer: if you don't supply which axes to plot into, it will assume the current active axes, which is the last one created here.

Comment: hi @dspencer I got an attribute error: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure'. It comes from 'out_norm.plot.bar(rot=0, color="b", figsize=(6,4), ax=ax)'. Why is that?

Comment: I would like to answer my comment. I can solve the issue adding a new loop below , `month = [1]`. This loop goes through 0 to 3. Finally, a minor modification was done in `ax=[i-1][j]` where `j` is the new loop indicator. Hope this helps.